# Any weird 'modular like mathematical space' that behaves like as if it is infinite until a threshold is reached?

Tags: calculus, geometry

(Using the advice from Mathoverflow, I have rephrased and splitted up the question)

3. (Might be a bit layman because I don't have rigorous math term to describe the concept) **Generalize it to mathematical spaces, are there spaces which are sort of like**

***a***. Having multiple $\mathbb{R}^2$ spaces that has a finite size k but acts like as if extending to infinity (see point b) sewed together
[image]

***b***. Has a weird property that for each trip wrt a parameter (e.g. time) if each distance of travel $D_i$ exceed a certain value k, you will hop to the corresponding location of the neighboring patch of $\mathbb{R}^2$ plus moving in this new patch by a distance $D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k$.

If your distance of travel for any of the trips does not exceed k, then no matter how far you travel, you will still be travelling within the same patch and *never reach the edge of it*
[image]

Using an example, (letting the parameter be time) property b is basically saying that you only jump to neighbouring patches (and travelling the remainder of it after dividing k) if your velocity exceed the threshold k (the size of the patch), otherwise you will *only be moving within a single patch forever, even if the total distance traveled exceed k*

> An attempt to formulate the above descriptions mathematically:
>
> **Question: Is there a class of mathematical spaces that has similar properties as described below or a more generalized version of it?**
>
> **a.** For the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, each patch is a $\mathbb{R}^2$ space and is described by ordered pair of integers $(p_{1},p_{2})$. Let $(0,0)$ be the central patch.
>
> Therefore every point $P_{x}$ in the space can be described by $(p_{x1},p_{x2},x_1,x_2)$ and the separation $S_{xy}$ between points is described by $(\Delta p_{x1y1},\Delta p_{x2y2},\Delta x_1y_1,\Delta x_2y_2)$ where
>
> $$\Delta x_jy_j=y_j-x_j,j=1,2$$
>
> $$\Delta p_{x_jy_j}=p_{y_j}-p_{x_j},j=1,2$$
>
> Let a path $\mathit{\lambda}$ connecting from $P_x$ to $P_z$ (both points are located on the same patch). $P_x'$ be the actual destination. $D$ is the total distance of the path $\mathit{\lambda}$ which is the sum of the distances of i trips (shorter partitions of the path i.e. $\lambda_i$),
>
> $$D=\sum_{i=0}^nD_i,D \geq D_i$$
>
> where $D_i$ is defined as the usual Euclidean distance between two neighbouring points in each partition
>
> $$D_i=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^2\left(x_{(i+1)j}-x_{ij}\right)^2}$$
>
> Let $d$ be the Euclidean separation between $P_x$ and $P_z$ defined as
>
> $$d=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^2\left(z_j-x_j\right)^2}$$
>
> **b.** Each patch has a threshold $k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
>
> If $\exists D_i>k$ then $P_x'$ has coordinates
>
> $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> (p_{x1}+1,p_{x2},x_1+D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k,x_2),z_1>x_1,z_2=x_2 \\ (p_{x1},p_{x2}+1,x_1,x_2+D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k),z_1=x_1,z_2>x_2 \\  (p_{x1}+1,p_{x2},x_1-D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k,x_2),z_1<x_1,z_2=x_2 \\ (p_{x1},p_{x2}+1,x_1,x_2-D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k),z_1=x_1,z_2<x_2 \\ \\
> (p_{x1}+1,p_{x2}+1,x_1\left(1+\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right),x_2\left(1+\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right)),z_1>x_1,z_2>x_2 \\ (p_{x1}+1,p_{x2}-1,x_1\left(1+\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right),x_2\left(1-\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right)),z_1>x_1,z_2<x_2 \\  (p_{x1}-1,p_{x2}+1,x_1\left(1-\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right),x_2\left(1+\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right)),z_1<x_1,z_2>x_2 \\ (p_{x1}-1,p_{x2}-1,x_1\left(1-\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right),x_2\left(1-\frac{D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k}{d}\right)),z_1<x_1,z_2<x_2 \\ 
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> If there is no $D_i>k$ then regardless of whether $D>k$
>
> $$P_x'=P_z$$

.

> For the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$
>
> **a.** Each patch is a $\mathbb{R}^n$ space and is described by a vector $\mathbf{p}$ with integer components. Therefore $\mathbf{p=0}$ is the central patch.
>
> Therefore every point $P_x$ in the space is described by ($\mathbf{p_x}$,$\mathbf{x}$) and the separation $\mathbf{S_{xy}}$ is described in a similar fashion to the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case as ($\mathbf{\Delta p_{xy}}, \mathbf{\Delta xy}$). The path $\lambda$, the points $P_z$, $P_x'$, the distances $D$, $D_i$ and the threshold $k$ are generaliation of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case. The vector $\mathbf{d}$ which go from $P_x$ to $P_z$ is defined as follows
>
> $$\mathbf{d}=\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{x}$$
>
> such that $d=|\mathbf{d}|$ and $\hat{\mathbf{d}}=\frac{\mathbf{d}}{d}$
>
> **b.** Each patch has a threshold $k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
>
> If $\exists D_i>k$ then the coordinates of $P_x'$ is
>
> $$(\mathbf{p_x+}\sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j \mathbf{e_j},\mathbf{x+}(D \hspace{1mm}mod\hspace{1mm}k)\hat{\mathbf{d}})$$
>
> where
>
> $$\epsilon_j=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> 1,\mathbf{d \cdot e_j}>0\\
> -1,\mathbf{d \cdot e_j}<0\\
> 0,\mathbf{d \cdot e_j}=0
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> where $\mathbf{e_j}$ are unit vectors along the $j,m\in [1,n]$ cartesian directions and $\mathbf{e_j}\cdot\mathbf{e_m}=\delta_{jm}$
>
> If there is no $D_i>k$ then regardless of whether $D>k$
>
> $$P_x'=P_z$$

I would like some suggestion or sources for further reading on such objects if they exist in order to learn more about their properties

Comment: Mathoverflow said this is not research mathematics, thus they suggest me to improve my question and post it here instead